# Dynamically add missing tags to a broken HTML string

Tags: javascript, html

I have a string of broken HTML. I need to search the string and add any missing opening or closing tags in JavaScript. No Regex, no jQuery. For example, I want to make a string like this:

```
"This <small>is <i>ONE</small> Messed up string</i>."
```

have proper form like this:

```
"This <small>is <i>ONE</i></small><i> Messed up string</i>."
```

Basically, the first `<i>` is a child of the `<small>` element. So I need to make sure the closing tag is placed properly and another opening tag for the misplaced original ending tag.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Parse the string, and serialize it again. There are various ways to do this.

```js
var str = "This <small>is <i>ONE</small> Messed up string</i>.";
str = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, "text/html").body.innerHTML;
console.log(str);//"This <small>is <i>ONE</i></small><i> Messed up string</i>."
```

```js
var str = "This <small>is <i>ONE</small> Messed up string</i>.";
var el = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument().createElement('div');
el.innerHTML = str;
str = el.innerHTML;
console.log(str);//"This <small>is <i>ONE</i></small><i> Messed up string</i>."
```

Comment: thanks for that answer. I'll go ahead and accept that, but what would a solution be for a headless browser that does not have a domparser?

Comment: @jmcgui05 Then you can use `document.createElement('div').innerHTML` as a parser, but only if you trust the string, because a malicious one could execute arbitrary scripts.

Comment: How would one go about this in plain Javascript, without using a Dom Parser?

Comment: @jmcgui05 A DOM Parser is plain JavaScript. You can also use `innerHTML` on an element in a sandboxed document.

Comment: sorry, what I meant to ask was, how can I do this without the browser. Both DOMParser and innerHTML use the browser no? What if I want to do this in my code, without help from a browser?

Comment: @jmcgui05 Ah, you want to do it using ECMAScript without the DOM apis. Then it's not trivial, HTML has a very complex syntax, so doing it manually is not recommended, but probably you can find a library for your ECMAScript implementation.

Comment: Thanks, I do not want to use a library. I think the fact my example shows html is somewhat over complicating the issue. I just want to be able to find a missing pattern in a string, and update the string to show the correct pattern. Maybe it is the same thing, I'm not sure anymore. I have an array of "tags" that I am expecting,so if one opening is present,the corresponding closing should also be present before the next opening tag. Would Regex be the easiest way to go,and if so,how do you handle that? I am bombarding you with questions now so I understand if I've maxed out this question

Comment: @jmcgui05 Not regex. If you can restrict the syntax to something simpler than HTML, write your own parser. Iterate characters one by one, when you find `<` you start a tag, `>` end it and pushes it to a stack. `</` starts an end tag, if it coincides with the last one in the stack you remove it, otherwise you keep inserting close tags until you find the proper start tag in the stack, and then reopen them.