# How can I add missing html tags to a string without using the browser?

Tags: javascript, html

I asked another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41915184/dynamically-add-missing-tags-to-a-broken-html-string/41915237#41915237) on how to fix a HTML sting with missing tags, and the answer I got was to use DOMParser, or innerHTML. Both of these worked like a charm, but that got me thinking, how can I do this without the help of a browser? For example, if I want to manipulate this string in Node?

The example string I mentioned is as follows:

```
"This <small>is <i>ONE</small> Messed up string</i>."
```

Which I want to fix so it looks like:

```
"This <small>is <i>ONE</i></small><i> Messed up string</i>."
```

My thinking was to use a combo of substring and join, and append a missing closing tag, or prepend a missing opening tag, but it seems an amateur move.

Comment: Your example uses Javascript, which requires a browser. Not sure what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: you want to it with text or in a html file ?

Comment: @CarlMarkham Updated to include a mention of node. If I want to make this change server side. Basically I am looking for the best possible way to update this string, without the browser. So think serverside Javascript if that helps.

Comment: It is just a string, not a file @Mohsen_Fatemi

Comment: To do this server side, you would need to load the Javascript file into a string and then manipulate it with something like regex. As it stands, your question is too broad and will attract too may opinions, which is not what SO is here for.

Comment: I would personally do this by building an object where tags were keys and contents were values and whenever I found a tag not closing before closing the parent tag I'd wrap the contents of the next parent node in it too, until I found the closing tag. But I'm not much of an expert in dom parsing methods so I reckon there might be more efficient ways to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most robust way to do this from scratch (e.g. without the help of the browser) would be to write a parser that understands your "broken" syntax and outputs the "correct" syntax as it parses it.  You would have to decide when to add the missing tags.  This would work out to several pages of code, but idea would be the following:

First write a tokenizer that can read your string in "tokens".  You would want to read pieces of text and categorize them as either start tag, content, or close tag.  This is easiest done by iterating through each character of the string in a state machine that keeps track of the context, understands the escape sequences, and emits a list of tokens.

Next write another state machine that reads those tokens.

- Every time you encounter a Start Tag token, you would append the token's raw value to the result string, and push the currently open Start Tag (if any) onto a stack
- When you reached a content tag, you would simply write the raw token value
- When you reached a End Tag, you would check if matched the current Start Tag.  If not, you would write a fake "Start Tag" to the result string to match the End Tag, followed by the End Tag's raw value.  If it does match the current Start Tag, then you would write the End Tag, and pop the most recent Start Tag from the aforementioned stack.  If the stack was empty, you would assume you were not in a tag anymore.

When done with all the tokens, if the stack was not empty, foreach Start Tag on the stack, write fake closing tags to the result.

Comment: Thanks for this. I will go ahead and accept. I really want to highlight my thanks here, as it was something that I just was curious about, yet there is sometimes a trend to just comment negatively rather than answering or moving on. SO is the largest online community for programmers to learn, share their knowledge and advance their careers.
So, I wanted to learn how to do this in a particular way, so I think that IS what SO is for.